# Compare each row of a matrix in Matlab with the remaining ones

Tags: matlab

I have a matrix `A` in Matlab of zeros and ones with dimension `BxM`.

Specifically, `A` contains all the possible dispositions of ones and zeros in `M` spaces considering also the order (hence, `B=2^M`).

- The matrix is built such that, for any `i=1,...,N`, `A(i,:)>A(j,:)` or `A(i,:)><A(j,:)` for `j=i+1,...,N`.
- Writing `A(i,:)>=A(j,:)` means that `A(i,h)>=A(j,h)` for `h=1,...,M`.
- Writing `A(i,:)>A(j,:)` means that `A(i,h)>=A(j,h)` for `h=1,...,M`, with strict inequality for at least one `h`.
- Writing `A(i,:)><A(j,:)` means that it is not possible to establish whether `A(i,:)>=A(j,:)` or viceversa.

For example when `M=3`

```
  A=[1 1 1;
     1 1 0;
     1 0 1;
     1 0 0;
     0 1 1;
     0 1 0;
     0 0 1;
     0 0 0];
```

Consider

```
B=cell(2^M, 2^M);
```

For any two comparable rows of `A`, `A(i,:)>A(j,:)`, I want `B{i,j}` containing all rows `A(k,:)` such that `A(j,:)<A(k,:)<A(i,:)`.

In the example above, the desired output would be

```
B{1,4}=[1 1 0; 1 0 1];
B{1,6}=[1 1 0; 0 1 1];
B{1,7}=[1 0 1; 0 1 1];
B{1,8}=[1 1 0; 1 0 1; 1 0 0; 0 1 1; 0 1 0; 0 0 1];
B{2,8}=[1 0 0; 0 1 0];
B{3,8}=[1 0 0; 0 0 1];
B{5,8}=[0 0 1; 0 1 0];
```

This code does what I want

```
B=cell(2^M, 2^M); 
  for j=1:size(A,1)
      for h=1:size(A,1)
          if  sum(A(j,:)==A(h,:))~=M && sum(A(j,:)>=A(h,:))==M %if A(j,:)>A(h,:) according to the meaning indicated above
              B{j,h}=A(any(bsxfun(@ne, A,A(j,:)),2) & any(bsxfun(@ne, A,A(h,:)),2) &... 
              all((bsxfun(@le, A,A(j,:)) &  bsxfun(@ge, A,A(h,:))),2),:);
          end
      end
  end
```

However, the code above is not feasible because in my actual case `M=20`. Do you have suggestions on whether it is possible to speed it up and, if yes, how?

One of the main problems of the code is that, for `M=20`, it requires to preallocate a cell `(2^20)x(2^20)` which, clearly, cannot be done.

On the other hand, at the end of the double loop, lots of cells are empty (because the if condition is not satisfied by many pairs of rows), and what I really need is to keep tracks **of the content and of the coordinates only of the non-empty ones**. Hence, maybe, a "sparse cell" could help me here.

Any suggestion would be really appreciated.

Comment: A cell on where values are not given is empty. You do not preallocate a `(2^20)x(2^20)` cell, you just preallocate a structure that is ready for being filled. A cell is already a "sparse" cell. You just have too much data. Try to approximate how many values of those `(2^20)x(2^20)` you need filled.

Comment: @AnderBiguri I see thanks, but it is not easy to predict the coordinates for which the if condition is satisfied. I don't see how I could do that.

Comment: Do approximate maths. If a matrix of size `(2^20)x(2^20)` was 1% sparse, and in each non-zero value you'd store a `double` (not a cell), you'd need 80Gb of RAM. Note that your proposition seems to need *more* values than that.

Comment: not much a difference it would create but your pre-allocation is incorrect. You  created an 8x8 cell and then its size may change to 9x9 in the loops depending on the `if` condition since last value of `j` and `h` is `9`

Comment: @SardarUsama Thank for pointing this out, there was an error in how I wrote `A`.

Comment: Your code does not produce the output desired by you. 
. Your code produces incorrect `B{1,6}`, `B{1,7}`
`B{1,8}`
, `B{3,8}`
`B{5,8}`

Comment: Now it should be correct. Thank you. The order of the rows inside each cell does not matter

Comment: the best way to speed uo the code is using the databases, which allows faster searching, execution and storing of your variables.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of pre-computing and memorizing the A matrix ("Old Matlab Style"),

write a "generator function" that gives you the row contents of the A-matrix for any row index. This way you convert a memory-intensive problem into a CPU-intensive problem. On top of that the subresults are independent on each other.

So what you need is

```
A_by_row=@(rowIdx)(....)
```

This way there is no need for lots of RAM, and you can distribute your problem to parfor, GPU or even multiple nodes, and then combine the subresults from sub-ranges.

Try this:

```
ListIdx=0; 
for j=1:B 
 for h=1:B 
  if sum(A_by_row(j)==A_by_row(h))~=M, 
    ListIdx=ListIdx+1, 
    B_List(ListIdx).Coordinates=[j,h],     
    B_List(ListIdx).Result=**YourCodeThatMakesAnArbitraryLengthVec‌​tor**, 
  end, 
 end, 
end
```

This way, in a structure 'list' you will get, for each entry, a coordinate and the vector of answers.

Good luck.

Comment: Thanks. May I ask you some further clarifications: my question is about how to construct the matrix B. The matrix A is already there.

Comment: Also, can you make an example? how can I access the content of a specific row?

Comment: Do you really need a sparse B matrix, or is it enough to have **a list** with coordinates and a list of answers for that row? I can only help you in the latter case.

Comment: A list of coordinates (x,y) and a list of answers for each (x,y) are enough

Comment: So, wrto my example, the list of coordinates would be I guess `[ 1 4; 1 6; 1 7; 1 8; 2 8; 3 8; 5 8]` and the list of answers would be `[1 1 0; 1 0 1];
[1 1 0; 0 1 1];
[1 0 1; 0 1 1];
[1 1 0; 1 0 1; 1 0 0; 0 1 1; 0 1 0; 0 0 1];[1 0 0; 0 1 0];
[1 0 0; 0 0 1];
[0 0 1; 0 1 0];`

Comment: try this: `ListIdx=0; for j=1:B,  for h=1:B, if sum(A_by_row(j)==A_by_row(h))~=M, ListIdx=ListIdx+1, List(ListIdx).Coordinates=[j,h], List(ListIdx).result=**YourCodeThatMakesAnArbitraryLengthVector**, end, end, end` This way, in a structure 'list' you will get, for each entry, a coordinate and the vector of answers

Comment: Apologies, but I think it is not clear what I want. If you run my code to construct the cell `B`, you'll see that only the cells `B{1,4}`, `B{1,6}, B{1,7}, B{1,8}, B{2,8}, B{3,8}, B{5,8}` are non-empty.

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't see a way to avoid the double loop, predict in advance the non-empty cells, and, hence, avoid to pre-allocate the huge cell `B`.

Comment: user3285148, are you being serious at all?

Comment: Thanks for your edited answer. I think `for i=1:B` should be `for i=1:size(A,1)`. Do you think there is a way to get rid of the double loop also? Using your suggestion I can get rid of the memory pre-allocation, but, still, the double loop when `M=20` makes unfeasible to proceed.

Comment: You say `I have a matrix A in Matlab of zeros and ones with dimension BxM` so that `size(A,1) = B`. using a constant is faster than invoking a function `size`

Comment: As to the double loop, it's not something that can be solved in 3 minutes.  You would have to actually transform the equations into a different form. I have done such things in the past using symbolic manipulation in Mathematica. 
Short of symbolic transformation, try parallel-for and/or writing the inner loop in C. Vanilla Matlab is particularly inefficient in treating boolean values (they are stored as double(!)) and type-casting typically makes it worse.

Comment: @JerzyDziewierz booleans are not stored as doubles

Comment: @excaza: true, but only if you specifically tell it to. If you do `q=1`, then `class(q)=='double'`; one has to do `q=true` to get `logical`

Comment: Why would any language assume to cast 1 as a boolean?

Answer (score 2):

Rather than brute force the answer, we can do a bit more math, to predict the outcome of the test, then just save the prediction.

We will make the following assumptions:

1) In array A, index location 'n' stores the binary representation of 'n'. Ex: A(3) = [0,1,1]

2) Because A(j) must not equal A(h), nor may the binary representation of A(j) be always less than A(h), the results must be lower triangular.

3) After plotting the locations of results for M=5, we see that there is a fractal pattern created by the compliance conditions. This fractal can be recreated using the Lucas Correspondence Theorem, "AND(NOT(j),h)=binomial_coefficient(j,h) mod(2)"

4) The following functions replicate your results.

```
function out = user3285148()
    M = 5;
    maxm = 2^M-1;
    for j = 0:maxm
        for h = 0:maxm;
            if predict(j,h)
                B{j+1,h+1} = [binaryarray(j,M);binaryarray(h,M)];
            end
        end
    end
    out  = B;
end

function out = binaryarray(in, length)
    out = zeros(1,length);
    bit = 0;
    while in>0;
        out(end-bit)=mod(in,2);
        in = floor(in/2);
        bit =bit+1;
    end
end

function out = predict(j,h)
    out =0;
    if h<j
        out = mod(nchoosek(j,h),2);
    end
end
```

You would be advised to either store B in a compact form, or use the predictions to pull the data as needed in leu of storing (2^20)^2 cells of information.

Please let me know if this meets your requirements.

Comment: You are effectively recreating the lower left Sierpinski Sieve for space B.

Comment: your function create 19 result for M=3 where there is just 7 valid pair for M=3

Comment: @darenshan, There are 19 unique pairs, if you bin those 19 pairs by their `A(j)` indexes, you get 7 sets.

Comment: Thanks. Why with M=5 I get a cell B 32x31 instead of 32x32? Also, with M=20 it takes infinite time.

Comment: Can you write only the lines that I need to get `B{j,h}` given `j` and `h`. E.g., `B{1,6}=[1 1 0; 0 1 1]` as in my example.

Answer (score 2):

I'm gonna divide your problem in 3.

1. Find the size needed for B
2. Find all the pairs of comparable rows in A with at least one row in between (left hand part of B)
3. Find all the rows of A in between each comparable pair (right hand part of B)

Couple of concepts I will be using

- Hamming weight: Number of 1's in a row
- Hamming distance: Number of different values between rows

**Part 1**

We know that rows *i* and *j* are comparable and hold *i*>*j* if and only if any 0 in *i* is also a zero in *j*, and any 1 in *j* is also a 1 in *i*. Meaning that the hamming weight of *i* is always gonna be bigger than the hamming weight of *j*

We also know that if the hamming distance between *i* and *j* is one, then the set of rows in between is going to be empty.

So for any *i* we can find its viable *j*'s by flipping at least two of its 1's into 0's.

Since we don't care yet about order, any *i* with the same hamming weight will have the same amount of viable *j*'s. And if the hamming weight of *i* is one or zero, then there are no viable *j*'s, because there are no two 1's to flip.

Now, we can find the number of viable *j*'s for a given hamming weight of *i* `w`, that are at a given hamming distance `d`, using the function `nchoosek(w,d)`. We know that the hamming weight of useful *i*'s is from 2 to `M` and that the useful hamming distances are from 2 to each `w`.

So we can generate a matrix `n_j` of size `M`x`M` in which rows will indicate hamming weight and columns hamming distance.

```
n_j = zeros(M);

for w=2:20
    for d=2:w
        n_j(w,d) = nchoosek(w,d);
    end
end
```

If we sum each row, we will have the number of available *j*'s for each *i* with a given hamming weight.

We can also find how many *i*'s with a given useful hamming weight there are in A, since it's complete and has every combination possible. We can use again `nchoosek`

```
n_i = zeros(M,1);

for w=2:M
    n_i(w) = nchoosek(M,w);
end
```

Now we can calculate the total number of pairs *ij* by multiplying the number of possible *i*'s on each hamming weight by the number of possible *j*'s on each hamming weight.

```
sum(n_i .* sum(n_j,2))
```

Which is huge in the case M=20, it's 3.4753 e09. And that's just the number of pairs, we still need to find the number of rows in between each pair. Its still an improvement from the 2^20 x 2^20, but I would be considering my options at this point.

Continuing, we can find the number of rows in between pairs as a function of the hamming distance of each pair. Basically its `2^d -2` it comes from the fact that hamming distance indicates you the number of values that you can flip to obtain a new valid row, minus the two original rows *i* and *j*.

And since we kept the original n_j separated also by hamming weights, we can multiply all together.

```
n_r = 2.^(1:M) - 2;

sum(sum((n_i*n_r).*n_j))
```

Which for the case of M=20 is 1.0925 e12. Meaning that B will have to be of length 3.4753 e09 and hold 1.0925 e12 values, which is in the order of I wouldn't try it

---

**Part 2**

Now to generate all the pairs *ij*. I believe that it is going to be easier and faster to generate a function to which we input *i* and it gives back the valid *j*'s.

You say you already have A, so you can directly index it, but I will use the `de2bi` and `bi2de` functions to relate index `i` to each row `A_row_i`

```
A_row_i = de2bi(2^M - i, M)

i = 2^M - bi2de(A_row_i)
```

First thing is to calculate the hamming weight of the row `i`, and use it obtain how many *j*'s are we expecting.

```
w = sum(A_row_i);

j_s = n_j(w,:);
```

`j_s` is going to be a vector of size M that gives us how many *j*'s we can get at a given hamming distance.

One can modify [code from this answer](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/78669-all-possible-unique-permutations-of-a-binary-vector) to create a matrix `flips` of size `sum(j_s)`x`w` with all the necessary flipping of 1's in `A_row_i` to obtain the matrix of `A_row_j`

```
flips=[];

for d=2:M
    c = nchoosek(1:w,d);
    out = ones(j_s(d),w);
    out(sub2ind([j_s(d),w],(1:j_s(d))'*ones(1,d),c))=0;
    flips = [flips;out];
end
```

It's worth noting at this point that `flips` depend only on `w`, not on `i`, so there are only M-2 different ones. In theory you could precompute them to speed up code.

Now that we have the desired flips of 1's we just need to apply them to a copy of `A_row_i` and recover the values of `j`

```
A_row_j = repmat(A_row_i,[sum(j_s),1]);
A_row_j(A_row_j==1) = flips;

j = 2^M - bi2de(A_row_j);
```

Now `j` contains all the valid *j*'s for the respective *i*.

You can now loop over all values from 1 to 2^M and build B ongoing, it's going to be an improvement over the double loop, but still for M=20, its going to be a while.

---

**Part 3**

If we have valid *i* and *j*, getting the indices `k` of in between rows is not that difficult. First we calculate the hamming distance `d` between `A_row_i` and `A_row_j`, and use this to create a matrix similar to `flips` that will help us build all the values of `A_row_k` and recover index `k`

The values to flip are those in which `A_row_i` and `A_row_j` differ from each other, and we can find these values easily with `bitxor`

```
A_row_i = de2bi(2^M - i, M);
A_row_j = de2bi(2^M - j, M);

d = pdist([A_row_i ; A_row_j],'cityblock');

flips = de2bi(1:2^d-2);

A_row_k = repmat(A_row_i,[n_r(d),1]);

flipable = repmat(bitxor(A_row_i,A_row_j),[n_r(d),1]);

A_row_k(flipable==1) = flips;

k = 2^M - bi2de(A_row_k);
```

Now you could loop over B, or run this code every time you get the *j*'s for every *i*, whatever works better for you.

As conclusion I would really recommend leave this as generators and call them whenever you need values, because for M=20, the amount of memory needed is impractical.

Comment: Thanks. Suppose I want to get just B{1,3}. How can I do it?

Comment: Say I have the indices i and j (I don't know whether the rows are comparable). How can I get the indices of the rows between them?

Comment: to get the rows in for B{1,3}, just set `i=1` and `j=3` and run the code in part 3 of my answer, and you'll have the rows in k. (You'll need `n_r`, that was defined in part 1, but it is only `n_r = 2.^(1:M) - 2;`

Comment: It is slower than the rows inside the loop in my example.

Comment: Oh I see what you mean, You still can use the second part of my answer to reduce the double 1:2^M for loop, for a single 1:2^M loop. Which combined with your code must be an important decrease in time

Answer (score 0):

easy math problem !

**A:**

```
Function out=A(row , number_of_bits)
        out=~bitget(row-1,number_of_bits:-1:1);
end

A(3,3)
ans =
     1     0     1 %which is identical with your A(3,:)
```

**B:**

```
function [out]=B(n1,n2,number_of_bits)
   c1=A(n1,number_of_bits);
   c2=A(n2,number_of_bits);
   out=zeros(1,number_of_bits);
   out((c1==0)&(c2==1))=-1;
   if sum(out)>=0
      out=zeros(1,number_of_bits)+2;
      out(c1==0)=0;
      out(c2==1)=1; 
      out=int8(out);
   else
      out=[];
   end

%example:
B(1,4,3)
ans =
     1     2     2 %number 2 serves as wildcard ("*") and means that element could be either 0 or 1, you should discard A(1,:) and A(4,:) from the results so the actual size_of_B is (2^ number_of_wildcards)-2
```

example:

```
B(1,1000000,20) 
ans =
  Columns 1 through 10
     2     2     2     2     1     2     1     1     1     1
  Columns 11 through 20
     2     1     1     1     2     2     2     2     2     2
  %which means that B(1,1000000) has (2^12)-2=4094 rows 

B(1,2,20)
ans =
  Columns 1 through 10
     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1
  Columns 11 through 20
     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     2
  %which means that B(1,2) has (2^1)-2=0 rows
```

**size_of_B:**

```
function out=size_of_B(b)
     if numel(b)==0
        out=0;
     else
        b(~(b==2))=0;
        b(~(b==0))=1;
        out=(2^sum(b))-2;
     end
%example:
size_of_B(B(1,1000000,20))
ans =
        4094
```

---

there is (2^19)*((2^20)-1)~= 5e11  pair of i, j for iteration
if you had a for loop which done nothing it gets about : 1100 seconds! so the amount of time for calculating all non-empty-B is huge(even if magically we know which element of B is non-empty before any calculation)

```
tic; 
 for i=1:1:10^9 
 end 
 toc
Elapsed time is 2.218067 seconds.
tic; 
 for i=1:1:10^10
 end 
 toc
Elapsed time is 22.165445 seconds.
```

---

```
%example:
 tic;
 M=10;
 n=1;
 for i=1:2^M
     for j=1:2^M
         if i<j
             c=B(i,j,M);
             if ~(size_of_B(c)==0)
                 d(n,:)=c;
                 n=n+1;
             end
         end
     end
 end
 toc
 [s,~]=size(d);
 s
Elapsed time is 10.095085 seconds. 
s =
          52905 %for M=10 there is 52905 pair of i,j with non-empty-B values;
```

for M=20 it takes about 10*4^10~=10M seconds ~= 121 days! (if the memory allows)

---

```
%script for plotting number of non-empty-B versus M
  d=[];
 for M=1:10
     tic;
     n=1;
     for i=1:2^M
         for j=1:2^M
             if i<j
                 c=B(i,j,M);
                 if ~(size_of_B(c)==0)
                     d(n,:)=c;
                     n=n+1;
                 end
             end
         end
     end
     toc
     [s,~]=size(d);
     d=[];
     h(M)=s;
 end
Elapsed time is 0.005418 seconds.
Elapsed time is 0.002238 seconds.
Elapsed time is 0.000933 seconds.
Elapsed time is 0.003058 seconds.
Elapsed time is 0.011650 seconds.
Elapsed time is 0.044217 seconds.
Elapsed time is 0.170286 seconds.
Elapsed time is 0.696161 seconds.
Elapsed time is 3.024212 seconds.
Elapsed time is 15.836280 seconds.
>> plot(h,'-o')
```

and estimating from the plot we could find that for M=20 there is about ~3e9 non-empty-B values; (and at least needs about 20~60 GB of memory to store B values like wildcard style which i used and much much more if you want to write all of B without wildcard style)
[image]

finally i could mention that exact number of non-empty-B could be calculated with an easy algorithm !

Comment: Thanks. I am not sure I follow you answer: the algorithm you provide solves the problem of memory allocation but not the problem of the double loop. Hence, for M=20, it is not feasible. Correct?

Comment: @user3285148 yes, but there is not a magical way that you could know if a B{i,j} is empty before you do any calculation :) , my answer just says that you could calculate any B{i,j} in no time  (even for M20) so why you want to calculate and store all of the B values?

Comment: and about feasibility , it is feasible but needs about 121 days of calculation to calculate and store all non-empty-B values :)

Comment: Thanks. Let j=4, i=5. Could you summarize at the end of your answer the entire code to get B{4,5} (without explanations)?

Comment: @user3285148 , first save function A and B in my post, then you should just write the following code in the command-line :   B(4,5,20)

Comment: OK, Thanks a lot.

Comment: I am not sure I get it. Say `M=3` as in my question and suppose I want to get `B{1,6}=[1 1 0; 0 1 1];` (see my example). What should I do?

Comment: @user3285148 after saving function A and B as 'A.m' and 'B.m' just write : B(1,6,3) in the command window for M=3, as i mentioned in my post number 2 in the answer serves as wild-card and means that element could be 0 or 1 so you see the following output :  ans= [2 1 2]

Comment: Could you kindly explain in Matlab language how I go from `[2 1 2]` to `[1 1 0; 0 1 1]`?

Comment: @user3285148 i used wild-card to summarize the answer (to reduce amount of memory and cpu time for calculating the answer) for example for M=20 and B(1,1000000) there are 4094 rows of answer but with wild-card summarization we could write it just in one row, each wild-card could be 0 or 1 so if an answer is [2 1 2] all of these rows are in the desired set : [1 1 1] [ 1 1 0] [0 1 1] [0 1 0] but [1 1 1] and [0 1 0] should be discard from the answer because they are the initial rwos wich we calculated B for them, so the answer is [ 1 1 0] and [0 1 1] ,

Comment: to create the exact and unsummarized answer you could easily write a function in matalab to get wild card style answer and convert it to expanded answer

Comment: @user3285148: feasibility: if this calculation is important, simply send it to a local university's supercomputer, (or a cloud, whatever) and you will get your answer in 1 day. That's clearly faster than tinkering with maths for a month and not getting anywhere.